# Can a coherent sheaf with no global sections have non-trivial higher cohomology?

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Particularly interested in coherent sheaves on projective varieties or complex manifolds.

Comment: I think not. Does writing down an injective resolution tell you anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. On $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$, the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(-2)$ has no global sections but $H^1(\mathcal{O}(-2))\cong \mathbb{C}$.